Ошибка во время обновление sqlcipher с 3x на 4x
SВ проекте используется библиотека net.zetetic:android-database-sqlcipher:3.5.9@aar.
Каласс OpenHelper:
public class DBHelperKey extends SQLiteOpenHelper {
        private static DBHelperKey instance;
        SQLiteDatabase db;
    
        public DBHelperKey(Context context) {
            super(context, "base.db", null, 1);
        }
    
        static public synchronized DBHelperKey getInstance(Context context) {
            if (instance == null) {
                instance = new DBHelperKey(context);
            }
            return instance;
        }
    
        @Override
        public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase sqLiteDatabase) {
            sqLiteDatabase.execSQL("Create table mysettings (id TEXT PRIMARY KEY,myvalue TEXT)");
        }
    
        @Override
        public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase sqLiteDatabase, int i, int i1) {
            onCreate(sqLiteDatabase);
            sqLiteDatabase.execSQL("DROP table if exists mysettings");
        }
    
        public void set(String mykey, String myvalue) {
            if (!exist(mykey)) {
                db.execSQL("insert into mysettings(id,myvalue) values('" + mykey + "','" + myvalue + "')");
            } else {
                db.execSQL("update mysettings set myvalue='" + myvalue + "' where id='" + mykey + "'");
            }
        }
    
        public void remove(String mykey) {
            db.execSQL("delete from mysettings where id='" + mykey + "'");
        }
    
        public String get(String mykey) {
            String res = null;
            Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery("select myvalue from mysettings where id = '" + mykey + "'", null);
            cursor.moveToLast();
            try {
                res = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("myvalue"));
            } catch (Exception ignored) {
            }
            cursor.close();
            cursor.deactivate();
            //db.close();
            return res;
        }
    
        public Boolean exist(String mykey) {
            boolean res = false;
            Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery("select count(myvalue)as cnt from mysettings where id = '" + mykey + "'", null);
            cursor.moveToLast();
            if (Integer.parseInt(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("cnt"))) > 0) {
                res = true;
            }
            cursor.close();
            cursor.deactivate();
            return res;
        }
    
        public void openDB(String key) {
            Boolean res = false;
            try {
                db = instance.getWritableDatabase(key);
            } catch (Exception ex) {
                Log.e("openDB_ex", ex.toString());
            }
        }
    }  

Необходимо было обновить версию библиотеки.
Письмо от google :  net.zetetic:android-database-sqlcipher has reported android-database-sqlcipher:3.5.9 as outdated. You may not be able to release future versions of your app with this SDK version to production or open testing.
Я обновил библиотеку на
implementation 'net.zetetic:sqlcipher-android:4.5.6@aar'
implementation 'androidx.sqlite:sqlite:2.4.0'  

После обновления приложение, ошибка лога "openDB_ex" в openDB() - android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: file is not a database (code 26): , while compiling: PRAGMA journal_mode.
Подскажите пожалуйста, решение данной проблемы.

Тут длинный топик по теме: https://discuss.zetetic.net/t/migration-from-android-legacy-to-regular-sqlcipher-version/5802
